# How to require a field with a value of "yes" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to be able to require certain fields if someone selects a value of "Yes" from a dropdown.  I've used the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(function () {
    $('#anyAdditionalInc').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "No") {
            $('#additionalIncomeSource').removeAttr('required');
            $('#additionalIncomeAmt').removeAttr('required');
        } else {
            $('#additionalIncomeSource').attr('required', 'required');
            $('#additionalIncomeAmt').attr('required', 'required');
        }
    });
});
```

My dropdown looks like this

```
<div class="form-group">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.anyAdditionalInc, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="col-sm-4">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.anyAdditionalInc, new SelectList(new List
            <Object>{ new { value = "", text = "----"}, new { value = "Yes", text = "Yes"}, new { value = "No", text = "No"}, }, "value", "text"), new { @class = "form-control", id = "anyAdditionalInc" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.anyAdditionalInc)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.  It doesnt seem to want to require the validation on the source and amt fields when selecting yes.

Answer (score 2):

A dropdown (I guess you mean a `<select>` element by that) doesn't have much `keyup` events. Try [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead:

```
$(function () {
    $('#anyAdditionalInc').change(function () {
        var active = $(this).val() != "No"),
            fields = $('#additionalIncomeSource, #additionalIncomeAmt');
        fields.prop('required', active);
        if (!active) fields.val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way that after validation if they decide to switch it back to no that it won't validate anymore? or even remove the validation from the fields?

Comment: If it is changed to `No`, then `required` will be set to `false`. Or do you mean to force the fields to be empty then?

Comment: To force the fields to be empty. and not show the validation message.

Comment: Hm, you might use something like `pattern=""` for that. But I'd avoid it, just ignore the fields. Maybe clear them.

Comment: clearing them would be ideal. Does that also remove the validation message?

Comment: I'm not sure what makes the validation message disappear, but the new code will clear the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Bergi answered the question from a client-side perspective, since you tagged the question `asp.net-mvc-4` I presume you may wish to know how it's done on the server side (where it really matters!):

You can simply check it in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo(SomeModel someModel) {
    if (someModel.anyAdditionalInc != "Yes") {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must select yes");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to push the logic into your model itself:

```
public class SomeModel: IValidatableObject {
   public string anyAdditionalInc {get; set;}

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
       if (this.anyAdditionalInc != "Yes") {
           yield return new ValidationResult("You must select yes");
       }
   }
}
```

Notice how the model:

1. Implements `IValidateableObject`
2. Has a method named `Validate` which returns the type `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`

During the model binding process this method will automatically be called and if a validation result is returned your `ModelState` will no longer be valid.  So using this familiar code in your controller will make sure you don't take any action unless your custom conditions check out:

```
public class SomeController {
    public ActionResult SomeAction() {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            //Do your stuff!
        }
    }
}
```